# Python script runs well on my laptop, but does not run at all on mine or my associates desktop

Tags: python, python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api

The problem involves a walkthrough for using the MSGraph SDK to build Python apps, (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tabs=aad). For some reason this runs perfectly fine on my laptop (windows 11, Python 3.11.6, msgraph-sdk version 1.0.0a16, azure-identity version 1.14.1), but returns a ValueError (expected 2, got 1) when run on my desktop (windows 10, Python 3.11.6, msgraph-sdk version 1.0.0a16, azure-identity version 1.14.1). This was tested on my associates desktop (windows 11, same everything else) and it returned the same error with the same stack.

Code snippet in question:

```
async def get_user(self):
        # Only request specific properties using $select
        query_params = UserItemRequestBuilder.UserItemRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
            select=['displayName', 'mail', 'userPrincipalName']
        )

        request_config = UserItemRequestBuilder.UserItemRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
            query_parameters=query_params
        )
        
        user =  await self.user_client.me.get(request_configuration=request_config)
```

Stack Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\jfarr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.18.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\jfarr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.18.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\jfarr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.18.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\jfarr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.18.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\jfarr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.18.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\jfarr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.18.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\jfarr\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\SwordPhish\python_server\src\main.py", line 96, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jfarr\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\SwordPhish\python_server\src\main.py", line 18, in main
    await greet_user(graph)
  File "C:\Users\jfarr\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\SwordPhish\python_server\src\main.py", line 51, in greet_user
    user = await graph.get_user()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jfarr\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\SwordPhish\python_server\src\api_outlook.py", line 49, in get_user
    user =  await self.user_client.me.get(request_configuration=request_config)  
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "C:\Users\jfarr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\msgraph\generated\users\item\user_item_request_builder.py", line 155, in get
    return await self.request_adapter.send_async(request_info, User, error_mapping)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jfarr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kiota_http\httpx_request_adapter.py", line 162, in send_async
    parent_span = self.start_tracing_span(request_info, "send_async")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jfarr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kiota_http\httpx_request_adapter.py", line 131, in start_tracing_span
    uri_template = ParametersNameDecodingHandler.decode_uri_encoded_string(      
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      
  File "C:\Users\jfarr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kiota_http\middleware\parameters_name_decoding_handler.py", line 92, in decode_uri_encoded_string
    name, value = name_value.split('=')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything, trying different combinations of versions hoping that one would be the magic ticket. Still very unsure of what is so different about the environment on my laptop besides the obvious difference in windows versions. However, that does not explain why this happened on my colleagues desktop as well so I am unsure of what to do next. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this is the full error traceback?  I don't see any code in there which would cause that error.

Comment: @JohnGordon My apologies, I just mistakenly copied the bottoms portions of the stack trace. Updated accordingly, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by something taking in 2 pieces of data but only 1 is being provided, if user is a tuple or list or other object this could be cause by one of the values inside of the self.user_client.me.get function not being passed into the object and instead it is just trying to pass a single value, but another function that later uses the tuple expects 2 values if that makes sense, without more context about what that function returns its hard to tell.

The change accross computer may cause this as some libarys or SDK resources may behave different on different OS versions.

Comment: I recommend trying to print out the value of user and also you have a extra space infront of the equals

Comment: this could also be caused by the function being called returning nothing once again just comment out or add fake return values for the get_user function and have a look at the user variable

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! User should be a tuple containing the user data requested in the query_params portion of the function. The traceback hints it being an issue with the libraries but I cannot figure out how to fix it since even my mates desktop, running the same windows edition as my laptop that runs the script, also throws the same error. Same library and SDK versions, same windows edition, different results. Thank you for your time!

Comment: as it turns out it was a libraries issue, pip list showed that the difference was in the microsoft-kiota-http package that had been updated recently. This was rolled back and now runs perfectly. Thank you again for your time!